# How to swap element position using Css?

Tags: html, css

I want to change the position of two elements using CSS.

The structure of my website is as follows and it show up `del ins`.

```
<span class="main-price">
  <del aria-hidden="true">
   <span class="price">
  </del>
  <ins>
   <span class="price">
  </ins>
</span>
```

No CSS is applied to these elements.

So I applied CSS like below.

```
.main-price{
       text-align: left;
       display: inline-flex;
       flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```

However, this will place the two elements vertically as shown below.

```
ins
del
```

So I re-applied the below css, still no change.

```
.ins{
display:inline;
}
```

I've tried many times other than that, but no matter what I do, it doesn't show up as `ins del`.

Can someone give me some advice on what to do?

Comment: The [order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) CSS property sets the order to lay out an item in a flex or grid container (mdn).

Comment: Hi, @Jax-p Thanks for answering! I never known about order css.

but looks like this is easy way to changing position.

When i need to change position again, i will try it!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `flex-direction: column-reverse`, use `flex-direction: row-reverse`.

Comment: Amazing! Its simply solved! Thank you!!

Comment: @cheonmu glad it helped. You can then mark the answer as accepted.